# Does anyone knows about EthItem?

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc-1155, wrapped-tokens

We already know that `ERC-1155` is a combination of `ERC-20` and `ERC-721`. Now, a new standard has arrived called EthItem saying that it is the combination of ERC-20, ERC-721, ERC-1155. So what is the difference between `ERC-1155` and `EthItem`?

As far as I have analyzed, I guess that *"ERC-1155 allows us to mint both ERC-20 and ERC-721 in a single contract, whereas EthItem allows us to convert Native items to Wrapped items and vice versa. Say for eg. a non-fungible ERC-721 or ERC-1155 token can be wrapped into fungible ERC-20 token"*. But is this correct? Can somebody please explain more clearly about *EthItem*? And what are those *native* and *wrapped item*?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Nobody knows about EthItem as a published standard.

The list of published standards is recorded at https://eips.ethereum.org/all

---

But if you have seen some draft, then maybe people are talking about it. And it would then be in a very early stage // definitely not at a point where you want to implement it.